# Install php-pecl-memcached

Tags: centos, php

I'm trying to install php-pecl-memcached in php v5.4.45 and Centos v6.5.

My command is following.

```
yum --enablerepo=remi install php-pecl-memcached
```

However I encountered the following error.

```
Transaction Check Error:
  file /usr/lib64/libhashkit.so.2.0.0 conflicts between attempted installs of libmemcached-last-libs-1.0.18-2.el6.remi.x86_64 and libmemcached10-1.0.16-1.ius.el6.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/libmemcached.so.11.0.0 conflicts between attempted installs of libmemcached-last-libs-1.0.18-2.el6.remi.x86_64 and libmemcached10-1.0.16-1.ius.el6.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/libmemcachedutil.so.2.0.0 conflicts between attempted installs of libmemcached-last-libs-1.0.18-2.el6.remi.x86_64 and libmemcached10-1.0.16-1.ius.el6.x86_64
```

I tried remove libmemcached10 by the following command.

```
yum remove libmemcached10
```

However, It doesn't work. The error detaile is following.

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
Setting up Remove Process
No Match for argument: libmemcached10
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: ftp.iij.ad.jp
 * epel: mirrors.hustunique.com
 * extras: ftp.iij.ad.jp
 * ius: archive.linux.duke.edu
 * updates: ftp.iij.ad.jp
Package(s) libmemcached10 available, but not installed.
No Packages marked for removal
```

Could you tell me how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Don't mix [IUS](https://ius.io) and Remi.  Many of the packages provide the same files, as your error output indicates.  These repos also have different views on conflicts, provides, and package naming; these differences result in the packages not working well together.  It isn't entirely clear what the exact problem is, but I can virtually guarantee it is related to trying to use both repos.  Pick which repository you want to use, and completely disable and remove the other one.

[IUS](https://ius.io) currently offers php55u-pecl-memcached and php56u-pecl-memcached, which use alternate names to avoid accidentally overwriting stock packages.

[PHP 5.4 is EOL](http://php.net/eol.php).  If you absolutely have to keep using 5.4, switch to CentOS 7, which uses that version, but will continue to get [security backports](https://access.redhat.com/security/updates/backporting) for the lifetime of the OS.

Here are some helpful commands you might need.

`rpm -qa | grep remi`

What Remi packages are installed?

`rpm -qa | grep ius`

What [IUS](https://ius.io/) packages are installed?

`rpm -qf /usr/lib64/libhashkit.so.2.0.0`

What package owns the file from the error?

`yum repolist`

What repos do I have enabled?